# Incorrect user information on providing token in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am providing token to get user information and getting user information by following method

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier());
```

Everything works fine but for one type of user it returns incorrect user information. For eg it returns user id 9 in case I am providing user id 10's token. I have different tokens for both users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: getAuthIdentifier returns an id or the token ?

Comment: getAuthIdentifier returns the id of that token holder @Maraboc

Comment: the only possible case is that the getAuthIdentifier  returns the wrrong id because find will return the user with id that id given !

Comment: Are you sure the token is unique for every user? if you run the SQL query in your DBSM does it return the correct id?, show us more info like table structure, getAuthIdentifier code...

Comment: `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier());` seems like two query for the same record to me. simple `Auth::user()` should give you a user record.

Comment: Are you sure your question is for related to 4 laravel versions?

Comment: Auth::user() returns incorrect record @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: What is the definition for 'wrong record'?